# How to upgrade rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to upgrade gems to 1.8 i tried installing  the respective debian packages but it seems its not getting upgraded

```
anujm@test:~$ dpkg -l |grep -i rubygem
ii  rubygems                               1.3.5-1ubuntu2                                  package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
ii  rubygems-lwes                          0.8.2-1323277262                                LWES rubygems
ii  rubygems1.8                            1.3.5-1ubuntu2                                  package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
ii  rubygems1.9                            1.3.5-1ubuntu2                                  package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
anujm@test:~$ 


anujm@test:~$ gem
gem     gem1.8  gem1.9  
anujm@test:~$ sudo gem1.8 install serve
ERROR:  Error installing serve:
        multi_json requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
anujm@test:~$
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is on how to update Rubygems itself — not any particular gem managed by rubygems.

Answer (score 511, accepted):

Install rubygems-update

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```

run this commands as root or use sudo.

Comment: i am getting this exception when i follow ue suggestion     gem update --system is disabled on Debian. RubyGems can be updated using the official Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get.

Comment: Here because of problems with unicode gem (https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode/issues/5): after having run answer's solution I had to run `gem pristine unicode` which re-built the gem and made it usable.

Comment: Works greate to update the rubygems on Debian system. Thanks!

Comment: I did this, and it seemed to uninstall all my gems!  They're easy to reinstall, but that surprised me.

Comment: I did this and all the gems installed on my machine got erased, and I had to install them all over again. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to install `minitest` on an NFS partition cf. https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1161

Comment: @Sacx, hamza(my teammate) want to kiss your forhead :) for this answer

Comment: `rubygems-update` is installed by default. So, it's the matter of running just `gem update --system`.

Comment: Usually you will never want to run this command as `sudo`. That will upgrade the system ruby. Consider using `rvm` or `rbenv`

Comment: Can anyone suggest a way to lock the RubyGems version for Docker? These updates would be applied once but leave the image unchanged.

Comment: Why would you want to run this as `root`?

Comment: `rubygems-update` can be missing. `gem install rubygems-update` was failing for me. Response was `➜ gem update —system
zsh: command not found: gem update`. Running the commands fixed it, although the latter wasn't necessary at least at this time, maybe because a fresh install. macOS Big Sur on a 2013 MBP

Comment: `rubygems-update` seems broken on Ubuntu 18.04:`/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:43:in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gem::BasicSpecification (NameError)`

Comment: Isn't update_rubygems and gem update --system the same? Both update the RubyGem system software, right?

Answer (score 68):

You can update all gems by just performing:

`sudo gem update`

Comment: This is an answer looking for a question.

Comment: without `sudo` if you installed gems as a regular user (installing gems as root is not very nice anyway).

Comment: The question is not "How do I update all gems?" but rather "How do I update RubyGems on my machine?"

Comment: This could lead into creating a mess - updating gems with sudo in a folder using rvm or other ruby environment switcher.

Comment: It seems people find this question when trying to update all gems, because the sons hold the father's name.

Answer (score 25):

Or:

```
gem update `gem outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

Comment: #brilliant Thanks for this one. I only added `--force` to keep the automation from stopping for overwrite confirmation

Comment: doesn't answer the question

Comment: Respectively with shellcheck errors fixed: `gem update "$(gem outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1)";`.

Answer (score 24):

I found other answers to be inaccurate/outdated. Best is to [refer to the actual documentation](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/UPGRADING.md).

Short version: in *most cases* `gem update --system` will suffice.

You should not blindly use `sudo`. In fact if you're not required to do so you most likely should not use it.

Answer (score 14):

You can update gem to any specific version like this,

```
gem update --system 'version'

gem update --system '2.3.0'
```

Comment: you command doesn't work on distribution based on debian gem update --system "2.1.0" ERROR: While executing gem ... (RuntimeError) gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories. If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.

Answer (score 6):

For me it sufficed to simply run

```
gem update
```

Comment: This is for updating your gems, not the rubygems software itself.

Comment: True, but this is the first Google result for searches like "update gem version", so I'm glad this answer was here.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use the debian packages, have a look at [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [Rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Comment: Debian package exist for Rbenv

Answer (score 4):

To update just one gem (and it's dependencies), do:

```bash
bundle update gem-name
```

But to update just the gem alone (without updating it's dependencies), do:

```bash
bundle update --source gem-name
```

Comment: This is for updating specific gems, not the rubygems software itself.

Comment: @thisismydesign I think I specified that this will update only a specific gem?

Comment: Yes but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: I see. But I know this will help someone like me who landed here first :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RVM, the command below helped me a lot when upgrading from a very very old rubygems (eg 1.3.7) that defies the more current update commands mentioned in the other responses in this thread.

```
rvm rubygems <version>
```