# Why is the rake call throwing an 'undefined method `cache' for Gem:Module' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I am trying to setup rails application but encountered the following error. When run

```
rake db:migrate --trace


un-defining :chars method on String for ruby 1.8.7 
compatibility
rake aborted!
undefined method `cache' for Gem:Module
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@mapwalk/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@mapwalk/bin/rake:23
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@mapwalk/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

ruby version: 1.8.7
rails version: 1.2.3
rubygems: 1.4.2

gems list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (1.3.3)
actionpack (1.13.3)
actionwebservice (1.2.3)
activerecord (1.15.3)
activesupport (1.4.2)
bundler (1.2.3)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
rails (1.2.3)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you add the migration file you're trying to run?

Comment: @JKen13579 In app their are 73 migration files..how can I judge which file is causing issue.

Comment: show `Gemfile` please. if you have

Comment: @Monk_Code please see `gem list` result.

Comment: you may be using a very old rubygems version, try to update.`gem install rubygems-update`
`gem update --system`

Comment: @Monk_Code I have tried it already, but unfortunately not working.. :(

Comment: The migration file you should look at is the one with `:chars` in it. Why do you have 73 un-run migration files?

Comment: @JKen13579 Actually I have un-run migration files because I am setting up this application first time. that's why I have to run all migration at first time.

Comment: Why don't you just load the schema? `rake db:schema:load`

Comment: @JKen13579 rake command is not working so how can I run `rake db:schema:load`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I just meant it's better practice to run `rake db:schema:load` instead of running a bunch of migrations from scratch. In [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239867/migrate-error-undefined-method-cache-for-gemmodule), the person had the same error you're having and got around it by downgrading his rubygem version. Perhaps that will work for you?