# Ruby on Rails - Lynda - Generating a Controller and View, Error on 'Rails Generate' Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and was following Lynda's Ruby on Rails essential training guide videos.

**In the getting started set of videos, we are shown how the 'rails generator' command works. I have followed all the steps, but every time I type in '$ rails generate' I get the following error:**

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
/Users/waleedrahamtullah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/waleedrahamtullah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/waleedrahamtullah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/waleedrahamtullah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:77:in `preload'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/waleedrahamtullah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/waleedrahamtullah/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How do you suppose I get around this?

Answer (score 5):

**The answer is in the Error:**

```
You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all`
```

**Update with this:**

```
gem install rubygems-update
```

**Then run:**

```
gem pristine --all
```

*All should be well.*

Comment: It gets me past that error but gives me another one:

Comment: Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/waleedrahamtullah/Sites/simple_cms/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")

Answer (score 0):

When I update

```
gem install rubygems-update
```

and then

```
 gem pristine --all
```

it didn't work for me.

But answer from [How to upgrade rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626143/how-to-upgrade-rubygems) helped to fix issue, but after that for some reason I had to install rails again and install all gems.

Install rubygems-update

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```

run this commands as root or use sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ruby with rbenv so I could run those as normal user.
However, generating new rails site

```
rails new blog
```

Shows warning about old rubygems.

```
    Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring.
```

Hmm. Checking the environment:

```
    gem env
```

shows

```
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
```

which is no good. As suggested on the internets I run:

```
gem install rubygems-update
gem pristine --all
update_rubygems
```

I am not sure if gem pristine --all was needed, but it can't harm anything. Checking the update status now

```
    gem env
```

shows

```
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
```

which is good. Calling

```
rails new blog
```

and everything went ok. No warning at all.