# Error when running gem specific_install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, specific-install

I am trying to run 'gem specific_install' (https://github.com/rdp/specific_install) to install another gem from a Github repository:

```
sudo gem specific_install https://github.com/RemoteRepository/foo_gem.git
```

After being prompted for my Github Username and password, I am able to download the gem.  However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `build' for Gem::Package:Module
```

Apparently, other people have the same error based on a comment to a specific_install related answer to this question: [How to install gem from GitHub source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source)

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/rdp/specific_install/issues/21) this is due to an outdated version of `gem` (rubygems).

Updating `gem` should fix it, if you are using rvm you should run `rvm rubygems current` (this worked for me), if you are not using rvm I believe you should follow [How to upgrade rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626143/how-to-upgrade-rubygems).