# Upgrading rubygems not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I wanted to upgrade rubygems and did the following

```
C:\>gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-2.6.10.gem
C:\>update_rubygems
```

gem install worked fine but when I do `update_rubygems` I get

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I am not sure what path is it picking up and from where. Any pointers for this?

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626143/how-to-upgrade-rubygems

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: We need more information. Since the system says it can't find the path, what _IS_ the path it's looking for and does that path exist? What does `gem env` output? (Copy/paste the output into your question, formatting it appropriately for readability.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `$PATH` variable to include the path to Ruby's bin directory.  You can add it to your path using something along the lines of:

```
 set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin
```

Just replace `Ruby200-x64` with the path to your `bin` directory