# Bundle: Missing Digest for Metadata.gz

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, bundler

i'm getting the following error when using bundler to install a the current rspec version.

```
The gem rspec-core-3.7.1 can't be installed because the security policy 
didn't allow it, with the message: missing digest for metadata.gz
```

So i tried to run

```
bundle --trust-policy=NoSecurity
```

but still getting the same error.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

from https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb

```
# TODO: This is for older versions of RubyGems... should we support the
# X-Gemfile-Source header on these old versions?
# Maybe the newer implementation will work on older RubyGems?
# It seems difficult to keep this implementation and still send the header.
```

I would try the following

1. Update [Rubygem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626143/how-to-upgrade-rubygems#13626200)

   ```
   gem install rubygems-update
   update_rubygems
   gem update --system
   ```
2. Change the ruby version you are using. If you are using `rbenv` follow [this guide](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions) otherwise for `rvm` you have to dig in [their website](https://rvm.io/)
3. [Update/reinstall bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in WSL environment with Ubuntu 20.04.

I use rbenv & ruby-build.

I solved it this way:

Open `rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/security/policy.rb` (ensure to replace Ruby version here to your current version).

Add this line:

```
return true # WARN: Workaround for a BUG!
```

Before this line:

```
signatures.each do |file, _|
```

Yes, it isn't a clear solution, but it works.

Previous answer didn't help me at all.

Perhaps, this problem relates to broken SSH connectivity in WSL. For example, when I type `ssh <any-domain>` in WSL console, I don't get any output.