# CocoaPods not installed - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cocoapods

Catalin 10.15.7, Xcode 12.3(12C33), flutter version 1.22.4 stable
I repeatedly tried to install Cocoapods with sudo gem install cocoapods, but got an error failed to build gem native extension

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210115-11087-1nv1wqg.rb extconf.rb
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/json-2.5.1/gem_make.out
```

also tried to used
 `gem update , sudo gem uninstall cocoapods , sudo gem install cocoapods` 
but not help me,tried
`rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock pod install`
can't run my project on the simulator

Answer (score 2):

For my case, the following solution working great with me

**if you don't remember cocoapods installing process was don by Gem Or brew,try both of 2 uninstalling option, to increase confirmation of uninstalling**

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
```

**next step start install Cocoapods**

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
```

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

```
pod setup
```

You can also review the following links
[first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65527864/12699382), [second link](https://www.google.com/search?q=brew%20cocoapods%20install&oq=brew%20cocoapods%20install&aqs=chrome..69i57.10528j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_EZUCYL6vLZOFjLsP5OyK6AQ15)

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Ruby for Catalina is too old for cocoapods.  I've had success by installing the ruby from brew, and either the cocoapods brew recipe, or the new ruby gem install.  (Sometimes one works, sometimes the other works, never sure why.)  Also requires some fidgeting to get PATH to put brew ruby ahead of the useless system ruby.  Ugh.

Comment: thanks for answer ... could you share me more information about Ruby installation.. i used this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626200/12699382 , and this https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ ..I'm still in-depth research to fix this issue