# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) MacOS M1

Tags: ruby, macos

I am trying to install cocoapods on my mac os air m1

when i was using the command from the official website

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

i was getting the error "requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210."

Then i followed the following answer ([How to upgrade rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626143/how-to-upgrade-rubygems))

> Install rubygems-update
>
> ```
> gem install rubygems-update
> update_rubygems
> gem update --system
> ```
>
> run this commands as root or use sudo.

but now i get the error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

i tried 2 other options below:

```
brew install chruby ruby-install
ruby-install ruby
```

and them

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

I suppose it should be working by then, but still getting the same error